# Get latest via the C# API

Tags: c#, sourcegear-vault

I'm trying to get latest from Vault using the `VaultClientIntegrationLib`

I am able to get latest by doing

```
GetOptions getOptions = new GetOptions();
getOptions.Recursive = true;
GetOperations.ProcessCommandGet(new string[] { diskPath }, getOptions);
```

But I want to know if there is a way to get a list of the files that got updated using `GetOperations.ProcessCommandGet()`, or if there is some other way to know what files got updated during a get.